# Add JSON array data into a temp or real table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have JSON like this

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{
    "prefix": "data",
    "body": [
        "Hello_1",
        "Hello_2",
        "Hello_3",
        "Hello_4"
    ]
}'
```

Now I want to add only "body" array into a table and get this output from table

[image]

Comment: Hey @dale, I got the query after some tries it is simple to use SELECT-INSERT query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tried I got the query as

```
SELECT [VALUE] AS NAME into #temp_table FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.body') 


SELECT * FROM #temp_table
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{
    "prefix": "data",
    "body": [
        "Hello_1",
        "Hello_2",
        "Hello_3",
        "Hello_4"
    ]
}'

select value Name
from openjson(@json,'$.body')
```

or the more explicit:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{
    "prefix": "data",
    "body": [
        "Hello_1",
        "Hello_2",
        "Hello_3",
        "Hello_4"
    ]
}'

select Name
from openjson(@json,'$.body')
with 
(
  Name  VARCHAR(20) '$'
)
```

output

```
Name
--------------------
Hello_1
Hello_2
Hello_3
Hello_4

(4 rows affected)
```

Comment: Thanks @david-browne-microsoft but i wanted to insert them into table. I got the query after some tries. Please see in my below answer